# Why multiple image display in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me Why multiple image display in react js ?I am trying to load image using canvas .I tried like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/o4o98kwy0y

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      src:
        "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*W1IPZj18aerIffSO321a2w.png"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const img = this.refs.image;
    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      ctx.font = "40px Courier";
      ctx.fillText(this.props.text, 210, 75);
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <canvas ref="canvas" width={640} height={225} />
        <img ref="image" src={this.state.src} className="hidden" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second image is because of the `<img />` tag. you need to hide the img in your `styles.css` file:

```
.App {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: how first image display ?

Comment: from where it takes src ??

Comment: It doesn't need `src`. It draws the image on canvas, when the image is loaded. check out `img.onload` in your `componentDidMount` method.